# How can I access FDA drug recall or warning letter data?

Tags: usa, openfda

How can I access FDA drug recall, or warning letter data?

So that I can use that information to predict the Drug Shortage 
using machine learning algorithms

Answer (score 1):

I hope you have additional data sources, of course, but what you're looking for is absolutely available.Also, the prescribing data that's available is far from real-time, though an unexpected spike in a drug with a manufacturing limit on the precursor (methylphendidate might be an example off the top of my head) could be useful to incorporate into the model.

I think what you're looking for is [here](https://open.fda.gov/drug/enforcement/reference/) specifically, though you may well find other useful information on the [OpenFDA](https://open.fda.gov/) site. Their open data is surprisingly useful in many ways. The link is to their API reference, which is a pretty reasonable overview. You can also download the data in bulk.

If you're not solely US-centric, you'll want to review the monthly data on prescribing from the UK NHS. Trends from that data might be helpful in predicting shortages.I can't add a third link, but the site is not hard to find.

Answer (score 1):

You can find U.S. Food and Drug Administration recall data on their site [here](https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/ires/index.cfm). You can export each enforcement report per week per year as a CSV. It is a bit of a hassle as you may need to aggregate the CSVs. You can also find related data on Enigma Public (disclaimer: I work here but I'm legitimately vouching for it) i.e [U.S. FDA Adverse Event Reporting System](https://public.enigma.com/browse/u-s-food-and-drug-administration-adverse-event-reporting-system/ddf42930-7e2f-4116-aaa2-08b62d548965).